# Different results when using script or pasting code

Tags: shell-script, variable

I wrote some unix code that performs arithmetic on my files and spits out a data matrix into analysis.txt (with added headers). However, when I tried to put this code into a script and run the script, the tabs (\t) separate my columns rather than actual whitespace.

Code that works:

```
for f in */Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/Alignment*/*.bam; do
 echo 'Processing '$f' ... ' 1>&2
 name=${f##*/}
 name=${name%.bam}
 pftot=`samtools view -c $f`
 pfmit=`samtools view -c $f chrM`
 pfgen=$((pftot-pfmit))
 pfratio=`python -c 'print float('$pfmit')/'$pfgen`
 ftot=`samtools view -c -q 30 -F 1536 $f`
 fmit=`samtools view -c -q 30 -F 1536 $f chrM`
 fgen=$((ftot - fmit))
 fratio=`python -c 'print float('$fmit')/'$fgen`
 echo $name'\t'$pftot'\t'$pfmit'\t'$pfgen'\t'$pfratio'\t'$ftot'\t'$fmit'\t'$fgen'\t'$fratio
done | awk 'BEGIN{print 
"name\ttotal\tmDNA\tchrDNA\tratio\tftotal\tfmDNA\tfchrDNA\tfratio"}{print}' 
> Analysis.txt
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in */Data/Inten... "the above code"
```

Run with:

```
bash Analysis.sh
```

prints the variables in the last echo line with literal "\t" separators.

I'm rather new, so any suggestions or resources are appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

`echo $name'\t'$pftot'\t'$pfmit'\t'$pfgen'\t'$pfratio'\t'$ftot'\t'$fmit'\t'$fgen'\t'$fratio`

will have the `\t` inserted directly. One can see something similar from a shell prompt via:

`$ export name=hello; echo $name'\t'$name'\t'$name
hello\thello\thello`

If the echo is changed to `echo -e` then the output will have tabs in it:

`$ export name=hello; echo -e $name'\t'$name'\t'$name
hello   hello   hello`

From the man page on echo:

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
>
> If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
>
> ```
>   \\     backslash
>
>   \a     alert (BEL)
>
>   \b     backspace
>
>   \c     produce no further output
>
>   \e     escape
>
>   \f     form feed
>
>   \n     new line
>
>   \r     carriage return
>
>   \t     horizontal tab
>
>   \v     vertical tab
> ```

Comment: A much better solution is to use `printf`, though.

Comment: @tripleee, indeed, but I was just following the OP's approach.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies echo and I will try with printf.

Answer (score 1):

See the `bash(1)` man page in the BuiltIn Commands section. The `-e` option is required for `echo` to interpret escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Is your interactive shell `bash` or something else entirely? [`echo` is notoriously nonportable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373) regarding how it handles special character escapes, like `\t`. In bash, plain `echo` doesn't expand them, but in e.g. `zsh`, it seems to.

```
$ zsh  -c 'echo "foo\tbar"'
foo     bar
$ bash -c 'echo "foo\tbar"'
foo\tbar
```

Bash's `echo -e` and zsh's `echo -E` invert the above behaviour.

Also, you probably want to [put those variables within quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373):

```
#/bin/bash
echo -e "$name\t$pftot\t$etc..."
```

Of course, the portable solution would be `printf`:

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s..." "$name" "$pftot" "$..."
```

But its not hard to see why one would want to use `echo` instead.